# How to set up React-Laravel project with out php artisan serve?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix, react-laravel

I have created a react-laravel project using laravel-mix. Right now I am run project using

1. npm run watch
2. php artisan serve
   So by this, I access project by : http://localhost:8000

I have also worked in laravel. In laravel, if we want to access project without php artisan serve then we can access using : http://localhost/project_name/public.

Now my question is, how can I access/execute react-laravel project without php artisan serve? Is there any kind of way to access/execute project without port? Because I want to set up react-laravel on live server and I don't want to continue open terminal on server after code uploading.

I will really appreciate your feedbacks.

Answer (score -1):

There are a multitude of ways to set up a laravel project. and it has nothing to do with the frontend suite you use whether its React or Vue, I will give you 2 options here to run a laravel application.

**1. vagrant/homestead**

Laravel Homestead is an official, pre-packaged Vagrant box that provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you to install PHP, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine. No more worrying about messing up your operating system! Vagrant boxes are completely disposable. If something goes wrong, you can destroy and re-create the box in minutes!
[Doc Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)

**2. XAMPP/WAMP/ or any LAMP stack**

XAMPP is a completely free, easy to install Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP, and Perl. The XAMPP open source package has been set up to be incredibly easy to install and to use.

[Link](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

**Personally I prefer Laravel Homestead since it contains everything out of the box for laravel Development. like PHP, Nginx, MariaDB, Node, etc...**